# Tomcat: When to use keepgenerated = false

Tags: java, tomcat

I've been looking at configuration options in Tomcat and I've found **keepgenerated**. This property is always **true**.

Why should I have it **false** at all ? Do you know any case when it's useful ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs of tomcat

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html

> **keepgenerated** - Should we keep the generated Java source code for each page instead of deleting it? true or false, default true.

Unless you need the source code, keep it true always.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm asking about any benefits of not deleting it. Does it have anything in common with debugging?

Comment: For debugging purposes , yes.